# How to output values from a list, with a condition

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am having trouble deleting values from my list:

```
// I made a scanner and 2  integers: input and devide.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = in.nextInt();
    // I make input into an array
    int[] ints = new int[input];

    // I fill the array
    for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++){
        ints[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // transform it into a list
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
       {
        intList.add(ints[index]);
        }
        int devide = in.nextInt();
```

Now I want to output all items in the list except for the values that are divisible by "devide" All help is appreciated!!!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far? What is your question?

Comment: When you remove an element from a `List`, the elements after it are shifted and take its place. How do you plan to work around this?

Comment: I don't have to work around it, I just need to remove the values from the list and the other ones can take its place.

Comment: Here's an example that illustrates the problem @SotiriosDelimanolis is highlighting: say `devide` is `3`. I imagine that you'd then want to remove elements `3`, `6`, and `9`. But when you remove element `3`, element `6` becomes element `5`, and element `9` becomes `8`. Similarly, element `7` becomes element `6`, and element `10` becomes `9`. Now what are you supposed to delete?

Comment: Then i want to just output all values other than the ones that are divisible by "devide"

Comment: @FriendlyCoder, i've updated my answer considering Sotirios and Justin's comments. see if that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the values and check if a value is divisible by divide and make a list of all the items found. Then remove this list from original list.

```
    List<Integer> deleteList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i : list){
        /* check if a value is divisible by divide, if so add it 
           to deleteList */
        if(i % divide == 0){
            deleteList.add(i);
        }
    }

    list.removeAll(deleteList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clean your code a bit. Anyway, something like this should work:

```
    List<Integer> finalListToPrint = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (Integer integer : intList) { //enhanced for loop
        if (integer % divide != 0) {
            finalListToPrint.add(integer); // add it to list
            System.out.println(integer); //you can also print it here
        }
    }

    //use finalListToPrint
```